# Notepad++ most efective log filtering method (filter out searches)

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I spend a lot of time working with logs searching for problems rootcause.
Most effective for me is to use function Find all in current document for some simple regex,
but sometimes I catch a lot of lines that hide most valuable lines.
What is most effective way, to exclude lines with exact pattern?

My dream way would be to have possibility mark some phrase in line of "filter result" window and mark to substract from result those lines matching pattern

Is there any plugin that helps or only way is to build more complex regexes ?

In other words in my logs are lines from some software components that I'm searching for. Then I find a lot of lines that are typical for normal device run and have some designation like "PowerSupply" but are generated according few patterns (so more than one regex matching) and it is few or more thousands, then between those lines there are also some single lines with sympthoms of failure, can be different and not match single regex pattern, also does not have to be labeled simply Error or similar label. I search for PowerSupply, I get few thousands lines and then I want to exclude lines with some patterns to have clear picture what abnormal is happening with the device

Comment: Do I understand it correctly? You are searching for lines with word `dog` but  it finds you a lot of lines with `no dog` which are not valuable for you and making the list of results messy? I don't know ho complex your usecase is, but maybe https://www.seelisoft.net/Linefilter3/

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Logs are taken from quite complex industrial devices, so patterns to exclude can be much more complex than simple example, so writing regexes with exclusions can be dramatic

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at using the `Bookmark line` option on the `Mark` tab of the find dialog.

[image]

Then, use `Search` > `Bookmark` > `Copy Bookmarked Lines`. Then in a new tab, paste in the copied bookmarked lines.

[image]

Or, invert the selection and cut the bookmarked lines rather than copy.

Comment: Bookmarks seems very usefull. I have some additional needs. First one probably can be fulfilled with macro, that will simply copy all bookmarked lines only to new window, to have line after line view like in search all in document. During analysis I'm doing few approaches so I would not cut original file. Second one is to "substract" or un-book lines that match given pattern - I do not see this option on the list, just invert selection